# Inequality that I believe can be conquered with Cauchy Schwarz I.E

Tags: inequality

There are ten real numbers $x_0, . . . , x_9$ with $x_0 = 0, x_9 = 9$. What is the smallest possible value of the expression
$$(x_1 − x_0)^2/1 +(x_2 − x_1)^2/2+(x_3 − x_2)^2/3+ · · · +(x_9 − x_8)^2/9$$?
I thought this problem had cauchy schwartz I.E written all over it , I was able to get the $x_i$'s to telescope down to $9^2$ or $ 81$ but then Im getting confused what will be the bi in the sum. will it be the sum of $1+1/2+1/3...+1/9$ or just $1+2+3...+9$ ? please help :(

Comment: well the expression is just $1+(1-1/2)x_1+(1/2-1/3)x_2+\cdots+(1/8-1/9)x_8$ so you can make it as small as you like, as there are no constraints on $x_1,\cdots,x_8$

Comment: maybe $x_i$'s are ordered?

Comment: Please clarify how $x_i$ are selected among 0,1,...,9

Comment: thats exactly how contest author worded it .. xi are real

Comment: @Randin: With $(x_0, \ldots, x_9) = (0, a, \ldots, a, 9)$ the expression becomes $\frac 89 a$, that can be arbitrary large or small.

Comment: @Randin Maybe we are assuming  $0=x_0\le x_1\le \ldots \le x_8\le x_9=9$?

Comment: lets assume that yes gimusi. and why was my question down voted twice??

Answer (score 0):

[cauchy schwartz inequality with writing the denominators as a sequence of radicals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGg3g.jpg) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGg3g.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXUVO.jpg by cauchy schwarz the (xi+1 -x i ) telescope leaving 9^2=81 but then we have the denominators which are the sum of integers from 1 to 9 , this gives a total of 9/5